# Determining which UIViewController subclass that a UITabBar Item belongs to

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a UITabBarController instansiated in my appDelegate, but I need a way to know when the user presses the different tab bar items (buttons on the tab bar).

-UITabBarDelegate protocol to the rescue (with the required didSelectViewController-method)!

With everything wired up in Interface Builder, how do I obtain a reference to the actual UIViewController subclass instance that corresponds to this tab bar item that was pressed?

I need this reference because I need to call a method in one of my UIViewControllers subclasses every time that tab bar item is pressed.

Any suggestions?

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)theTabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{   
    NSLog(@"%@", [[self.tabBarController selectedViewController] nibName]); // nil, no success here     

    if ([theTabBarController selectedIndex] == 1) {         
        MySecondViewController *reference = (MySecondViewController *) viewController;      

    if ([reference isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        NSLog(@"OMG. It's a UINavigationController class??!"); // kicks in for some reason, shouldn't reference be a MySecondViewController
    }   
}
```

Comment: It appears that you are you using a `UINavigationController` in the tab that is activated. If so, you need to get the top view controller from the `UINavigationController`, and you should get your `MySecondViewController` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly I am not understanding your question correctly, but it seems that what you're asking for is simply the "viewController" parameter which is passed into the method call you've mentioned

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)theTabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

UITabBarController also has a property to get the same info

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) UIViewController *selectedViewController
```